# get the first three items having the highest ratings from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

hello i have a question.
i need to get the 3 object that has the highest rating (for now i have 3 by it dosent matter because i need to add more)
how can i do it?
i am trying to use sort and spread
but because that is array of object and another array (rating)
i get confused
thanks

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([
    {
      movieName: "godfather",
      info: "the rise of  corelone family  all mater is respect,money,woman but the youngest son michal has a diffrent plans...",
      picture: "pictures/godfather.jpg",
      rating: [10, 5, 1],
    },
    {
      movieName: "scarface",
      info: "the rise of  tony montata the badass man of miami want to control miami and be the number 1 of the cocaine provider ...",
      picture: "pictures/scarface.jpg",
      rating: [10, 9, 2],
    },
    {
      movieName: "the-dark-knight",
      info: "you all knew that he will come the batman! come to fight with his popular rival the joker...",
      picture: "pictures/the-dark-knight-poster.jpg",
      rating: [10, 10, 9],
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: How do you count the rating of one movie? By adding all the ratings from the array?

Comment: You need the three objects with the highest rating or the highest average rating ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
const rates = movies
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const sumRate = curr.rating.reduce((acc2, curr2) => acc2 + curr2, 0)
    const rate = sumRate / curr.rating.length
    acc.push({ ...curr, rate })
    return acc
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => a.rate - b.rate)

const highestRate = rates[rates.length - 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can sort by average and total rating using the `sort` method ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

### Sort by average rating

```js
const getAverage = (array) => {
    const total = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    return total / array.length;
};

setMovies(prev => (
    prev.sort((a, b) => {
        const aRating = a.rating;
        const bRating = b.rating;
        if (getAverage(aRating) > getAverage(bRating)) return -1;
        if (getAverage(aRating) < getAverage(bRating)) return 1;
        return 0;
    })
));
```

### Sort by total rating

```js
const getTotal = (array) => {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

setMovies(prev => (
    prev.sort((a, b) => {
        const aRating = a.rating;
        const bRating = b.rating;
        if (getTotal(aRating) > getTotal(bRating)) return -1;
        if (getTotal(aRating) < getTotal(bRating)) return 1;
        return 0;
    })
));
```

Comment: thank you so much! i use this approach